# speaking in Agora.io voice chat feature?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

Is it possible to know which speaker is speaking in Agora.io voice chat feature?have recently started using Agora.io's voice chat feature in my Unity multiplayer game. I want to start animation local player object as soon as a specific person in a channel starts speaking and

Answer (score 1):

To detect the active speaker or if a user is broadcasting audio use the  **EnableAudioVolumeIndication** and **Audio Volume Indication Callback** methods.

First you need to enable the VolumeIndication

```
public int EnableAudioVolumeIndication (int interval, int smooth);
```

And then you need to implement the handler to be get the volume details.

```
public delegate void VolumeIndicationHandler (AudioVolumeInfo[] speakers, int speakerNumber, int totalVolume);
```

Full Documentation:

- [EnableAudioVolumeIndication](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/game_unity?platform=Unity#set-the-audio-volume)
- [VolumeIndicationHandler](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/game_unity?platform=Unity#audio-volume-indication-callback-volumeindicationhandler)